# How to get first item from comma separated list of url's in JSON file?

Tags: jquery, json

How do I get the first url from a comma separated list in a JSON file? I don't get the img source in below code to work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("assets/data/data-package-1.json", function(data) {
    var myData = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        myData += '<tr>';
        myData += '<td>' + '<img src="' + value.images[0] + '"/>' + '</td>';
        myData += '<td>' + value.type + '</td>';
        myData  += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#my-table').append(myData);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is in data-package-1.json? A sample data (structure) would help.

Comment: Why is it a comma-separated list instead of a JSON array?

Comment: Use `value.images.split(",")[0]`

Comment: Thank you Barmar. It works perfectly! Actually I don't know why the developer who made the JSON has choosen a comma-separated list over a JSON array. It would have been more simple indeed.